# Too much noise on high samples

Tags: rendering

Why I still have too much noise on my 10,000 samples and 0.01 Noise Threshold (Denoiser blured this noise) I rendered at 1920x1080 (100%) on CPU (Ryzen 5 3600) because my GPU is slower (GTX 1050 Ti).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it'd be great if you share your **.blend** file so we can understand the problem better.

The big cube that cover whole scene is a volumetric right? If so, volumetrics are tend to increase noise in the scene, so your scene needs further optimization. I would analyze it better if you share your **.blend** file.